# Why does Ionic-2 Calendar gives "Invalid Date" after passing to js Date() and when calling onViewTitleChanged?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2-calendar

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting an "Invalid Date" after passing it to `var sDate = new Date(title)`. My goal is to only get the current month, so I could query it on sqlite.

[image]

Using ionic 4, ionic2-calendar and angular on ionic-cordova.

I have the following ionic2-calendar method.

```
onViewTitleChanged(title)
{
    console.log("onViewTitleChanged:")
    console.log(title)

    var sDate = new Date(title)
    console.log("check Date:")
    console.log(sDate)

    console.log("typeof:")
    console.log(typeof title);
}
```

Which outputs the following.

> onViewTitleChanged:
>   May 2020
>
> check Date:
>   Invalid Date
>
> typeof:
>   string

[image]

I tried to run a single file date.js and tried to run on node.

> node date.js

And gives the following output.

sDate:
2020-04-30T16:00:00.000Z

I also tried to run a code-snippet, works fine. But on the ionic-device, it does not?

```js
var title = "May 2020"

console.log("onViewTitleChanged:")
console.log(title)

var sDate = new Date(title)
console.log("check Date:")
console.log(sDate)

console.log("typeof:")
console.log(typeof title);
```

I could not get why it does not work on the emulator (iOS), debugging using Safari nor the device.

Comment: what is in ur `date.js` ?

Comment: The date string that you should pass should be in `ISO 8601` format(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format). Safari is strict in this. You can try to use some data library to covert it to valid format

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve my issue. Thanks for the suggestion that I should pass a valid ISO 8601 on Safari.

My solution was just to split the passed Month and Year and re-formatted it.

```js
// Passed Month, Year Only
var title = "May 2020"

// Split Ionic Month and Year
var sd = title.split(" ")

// Format to Proper Date
var pd = sd[0] + ' 1, ' + sd[1]

var sDate = new Date(pd)
console.log("Proper Date Parsed:")
console.log(sDate)

var month = '0' + (sDate.getMonth() + 1);
var year = sDate.getFullYear();

console.log("Month(slice):" + month.slice(-2))
console.log("Year(slice):" + year)
```

Works now.